# WHERE conditional queries without using string

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have to return the State corresponding to its City in the `address_table` sent through a POST request. I used a `WHERE` clause in the query, but it requires a string. What should I do if I want it to contain the city returned from a method in `AddressManager`?

This code is working if the City sent as a post request is what I put in `WHERE a.city = ''`

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long>
{       
    @Query("SELECT a.state FROM address_table a WHERE a.city = '' ") 
    String getState();
    // the blank city should be the city from user.setCity (ua.getCity())
}
```

**Manager**

```
@Component 
public class AddressManager
{
    @Autowired
    private AddressRepository aRepo;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository uRepo    

    public void save(UserAddressDto ua)
    {               
        User user = new User();
            
        user.setCity (ua.getCity());
        user.setState(aRepo.getState());
                    
        uRepo.save(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think in your `@Query` you are mixing jpa and native SQL. What kind of statement are you going to write? If it is JPA you should also post the Entities code e.g. `Address`, `City` etc. If it is going to be an SQL query you should post your DB table structure e.g. `address_table` and city table

Answer (score 0):

If `city` is a String then:

**AddressRepository**

```
@Query("SELECT a.state FROM address_table a WHERE a.city = :city ", nativeQuery = true) 
String getState(@Param("city") String city);
```

**AddressManager**

```
user.setCity (ua.getCity());
user.setState(aRepo.getState(ua.getCity()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JPQL query with a named parameter would look like this taking into account that several states may have namesake cities:

```java
@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long>
{       
    @Query("SELECT a.state FROM Address a WHERE a.city = :city ")
    List<String> getState(@Param("city") String city);
}
```

As for the condition, this may be implemented using `CASE ... END` a similar way:

```java
    @Query("SELECT a.state FROM Address a WHERE a.city = (CASE :city = '' THEN :userCity ELSE :city END) ") 
    List<String> getState(
        @Param("city") String city,
        @Param("userCity") String userCity
    );
```